# PHP-FPM8.0 Fatal Error Insufficient shared memory!

Tags: server, apache2, php, php-fpm

I am running LAMP in VBox6.1 with Ubnutu Server 20.04.

**Cause**
This morning I removed all attachments to my vdi (optical disk & shared folders) and then used `vboxmanage` to `--compact` my vdi as recommended.  (Compacting may be the cause of the problem or a bad php update.)

**Problem**
In any case, after reattaching my shared folders and rebooting my vdi, I was greeted by

```
● php8.0-fpm.service loaded failed failed The PHP 8.0 FastCGI Process Manager
...
Starting The PHP 8.0 FastCGI Process Manager...
php-fpm8.0[5192]: [15-Jan-2023 07:41:57] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'apcu.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20200930/apcu.so (/usr/lib/php/20200930/apcu.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20200930/apcu.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20200930/apcu.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
php-fpm8.0[5192]: [15-Jan-2023 07:41:57] NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'redis.so' (tried: /usr/lib/php/20200930/redis.so (/usr/lib/php/20200930/redis.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib/php/20200930/redis.so.so (/usr/lib/php/20200930/redis.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
php-fpm8.0[5192]: Sun Jan 15 07:41:57 2023 (5192): Fatal Error Insufficient shared memory!
php8.0-fpm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=254/n/a
php8.0-fpm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
ystemd[1]: Failed to start The PHP 8.0 FastCGI Process Manager.
....
```

**Troubleshooting**
I figured a bad php update knocked out apcu and redis so I ran: `apt install --reinstall php8.0-apcu && apt install --reinstall php8.0-redis` and this solved two parts of my problem.

However, I am currently stuck with this error:

```
● php8.0-fpm.service loaded failed failed The PHP 8.0 FastCGI Process Manager
...
Starting The PHP 8.0 FastCGI Process Manager...
php-fpm8.0[4226]: Sun Jan 15 08:39:51 2023 (4226): Fatal Error Insufficient shared memory!
php8.0-fpm.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=254/n/a
php8.0-fpm.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Failed to start The PHP 8.0 FastCGI Process Manager.
...
```

**Useful Info**

- All other versions of php-fpm are working correctly
- Attempting to reinstall php8.0-fpm results i the same problem
- The are zero limits on my shared memory:
- `# sysctl -a | grep kernel.shm`

  ```
  kernel.shm_next_id = -1
  kernel.shm_rmid_forced = 0
  kernel.shmall = 18446744073692774399
  kernel.shmmax = 18446744073692774399
  kernel.shmmni = 4096
  ```
- I booted from LiveCD and ran `e2fsck -cfyv /dev/mapper/vgubuntu-vg` (no errors)
- The php8.0 php.ini confirms that shared memory is configured properly:

  ```
  root@test:~# php8.0 -i | grep -i sysvshm
  /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini,
  sysvshm
  sysvshm support => enabled
  root@test:~# php8.0 -i | grep -i sysvsem
  /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini,
  sysvsem
  sysvsem support => enabled
  root@test:~# php8.0 -i | grep -i sysvmsg
  /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini,
  sysvmsg
  sysvmsg support => enabled
  root@test:~# php8.0 -i | grep -i shmop
  /etc/php/8.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini,
  shmop
  shmop support => enabled
  ```

I also considered that maybe another application was consuming allof the shared memory and causing php8.0-fpm to fail... **not** the case:

```
# ipcs -m --human

------ Shared Memory Segments --------
key        shmid      owner      perms      size       nattch     status      
0x64000630 4          root       600          1.1M     4
```

So at this point, I am stumped.

**Question:**
How do I get php8.0-fpm-running again?

Comment: Solution:  apt remove --purge php8.0* && apt install php8.0